# R boxplot() and summary() of frequency table

Tags: r, matrix, boxplot

I have a data matrix that contains two columns: value, freq.
I want to make a boxplot of value, weighted by frequency column.
The matrix is sorted by value.

```
> data[1:5,]
  value freq
1    28 1184
2    29 1063
3    30 1000
4    31  976
5    32  944
```

I have read many answers about similar problems, the only solution I found is this. http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/boxplot-with-frequencies-counts-td4660330.html

```
counts<-matrix(rep(data$value,data$freq), ncol=1, byrow=TRUE)
boxplot(counts)
```

The problem with building a matrix repeating every value is that it makes an incredibly large matrix.  While R was able to do this in its memory, I am working on R on a virtual machine (Ubuntu) and I wonder for really big data sets if there might be an alternate approach.  Perhaps there is a library built for this purpose?

Comment: Question: how did you produce the data with value/freq? I assume the data must be in-memory then. Perhaps a sampling approach would help. You could scale the freq column appropriately.

Comment: I parsed text files using Python, built a frequency table summarizing the files, and then wrote a .csv file.  Then, I used readcsv() command in R.

Comment: You can use ggplot. It hás a "weight" parameter:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204175/ggplot2-boxplot-from-count-table?newreg=5fc4e4c6153840cea0f5409a5ef6989d

Answer (score 1):

You need data.table library .
Here is an example of improved performance

using diamonds dataset in ggplot2 library

```
> count <- as.data.table(rep(diamonds$carat,diamonds$depth),ncol=1,byrow=TRUE)
> count1 <- system.time(matrix(rep(diamonds$carat,diamonds$depth),ncol=1,byrow=TRUE))
> count1
   user  system elapsed 
   0.15    0.02    0.18 
> count <- system.time(as.data.table(rep(diamonds$carat,diamonds$depth),ncol=1,byrow=TRUE))
> count
   user  system elapsed 
   0.04    0.03    0.06
```

Comment: actually, the bottleneck is in the boxplot:  `system.time(boxplot(count1))` or `system.time(boxplot(count))` both takes about 5 secs.

Answer (score 0):

By scaling your freq columns, you can overcome memory limitations and still get the same boxplot in your case. See the code below. However, if you observe/suspect outliers and want these in your boxplot, you will have to handle/plot them separately.

```
    > data<-data.frame(value=c(28,29,30,31,32),freq=c(1184,1063,1000,976,944))
    > counts<-matrix(rep(data$value,data$freq), ncol=1, byrow=TRUE)
    > length(counts)
    [1] 5167
    > boxplot(counts,at=1,xlim=c(0,3))
    > counts<-matrix(rep(data$value,round(data$freq/100)), ncol=1, byrow=TRUE)
    > length(counts)
    [1] 52
    > boxplot(counts,at=2,add=T)
```

[image]