# ggplot2 boxplot from count table

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a count table that I have generated with another tool, and I would like to get a boxplot from it with ggplot2.

For instance, suppose that I have:

```
df1 = data.frame(nSiblings = c(0, 1, 2), count = c(10, 15, 12))
```

instead of

```
df2 = data.frame(nSiblings = c(rep(0, 10), rep(1, 15), rep(2, 12)))
```

I know how to produce a boxplot from the second data frame:

```
qplot(y=df2$nSiblings, x=1, geom = "boxplot")
```

I know how to produce a histogram from the first data frame:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = nSiblings, y = count)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

But how can I get a boxplot from the first data frame?

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need another tool to generate df1 from df2. You could do for example `library("dplyr"); df1 <- count(df2, nSiblings)`. Easy to do it with base R too.

Comment: @antoine-sac: Thanks, but I knew that.  This data frame is the output of another tool (and, actually, the counts may be greater than one million).

Comment: There is also an option of 'regenerating' your large dataframe, but when counts are >1e6 that's not computationally/memory efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ggplot is able to work with weights, so you could try this:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=1,y=nSiblings,weights=count)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: For me (R version 3.6.3, ggplot2 version 3.2.1) it needs to be 'weight' not 'weights' (drop the 's' at the end). Otherwise an error is thrown.